# Can't move opened e-mails in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, move

I recently upgraded Thunderbird to version 115.0.1 and since then, the MOVE TO dropdown doesn't work when I am reading an e-mail.

I am referring to this option:

[image: MOVE TO button]

When I browse my e-mails (without opening the mail itself), and I use this dropdown, the e-mail that is selected will move to the chosen folder just fine. However, when I open a particular e-mail to read, then the functionality breaks down. The dropdown is still there, and I can still select a folder to move the e-mail to, but it doesn't do anything. I looked at the log, and this error is produced when selecting a folder to move the mail into:

> console.error: "An error occurred executing the cmd_moveMessage
> command: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057
> (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIMsgDBView.doCommandWithFolder]"
> nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS
> frame :: chrome://messenger/content/mailCommon.js :: cmd_moveMessage
> :: line 167"  data: no]"

I am using POP3.

Comment: What version did you use before the upgrade? I am asking because the "Move to" dropdown does not appear in my TB 102 installation, and is not available in the menu "Customize" window.

Comment: better is to update to Thunderbird version: 115.3.2;
for me it solved the problem;
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide a solution or a workaround, but I guess I can explain it:

As with every major version in recent times, in TB 115, the TB folks have managed to break all sorts of things that had been working in previous versions. There are still dozens of new bugs of various severity in TB 115, and I am quite sure that your problem is due to one of them.

IMHO, your options are:

- Report the bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home). But be prepared that nothing will happen about it for a long time; some bugs there are several years old without anybody ever caring. However, bug reports are recommended in every case.
- Live with the situation and hope that it will be resolved one day. This is not completely unlikely if a lot of other users have the same problem.
- A good part of TB is based on JavaScript. Eventually you can figure out what's going on and correct it yourself, or you could ask developers you know, e.g., in your company.

Finally, another option, and probably the best one, would be to switch to [Betterbird](https://betterbird.eu). BB is based on the current TB version, but has additional bug fixes and features added. In contrast to the TB team, its author is very helpful, fast and competent. I am personally using BB since several years and confirm that it is always based on the latest TB version. BB profiles are 100% compatible with TB profiles, so you can switch between the two at any time (given you are using the same version).

[ Disclaimer: I am not involved in or related to the Betterbird project in any way, except that I am in close contact with its author from time to time to ask him to fix certain TB bugs in BB, and to help him with such bug fixes by thorough tests in production environments with large email stores. ]

If you report the bug at bugzilla as described above and then drop a comment below with a link to the bug report, I eventually could ask the BB author whether he's willing to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't solve my issue directly but I will mark as accepted for lack of a directly solving solution.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. While it doesn't solve your issue, the offer to contact the BB author still stands :-) Of course, that would only help if you could switch at all, and I currently don't know whether he would actually be willing to fix that bug.